# How to use Material UI component in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to react and to Material UI, and I can't figure out how to use their components with their styling an example would be.
I have this card component from the docs (take the card with the lizard as example)

https://material-ui.com/demos/cards/

How do I use it in my class component? 
If i copy just the render it works but  don't get the same result as the example.
What is this?

```
ImgMediaCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ImgMediaCard);
```

I tried searching online but I can't figure it out any help is appreciated

Myclass

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import SkipPreviousIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious";
import PlayArrowIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow";
import SkipNextIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SkipNext";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

export default class Serie extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      serie: this.props.serie
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    const { id, title, apiname, description, image, likes } = this.props.serie;
    return (
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Card >
          <div >
            <CardContent >
              <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                {title}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
                Mac Miller
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <div>
              <IconButton aria-label="Previous">
                <SkipNextIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton aria-label="Play/pause">
                <PlayArrowIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton aria-label="Next">
                <SkipNextIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </div>
          <CardMedia
            image={image}
            height="140"
            title=" image"
          />
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your class look like?

Comment: Do I put in the question?

Comment: What is the actual difference to the example? Can you share screenshots? And for the sake of a solution the code you are using - How you use the card in the render? What styling to you attach?

Comment: There is no major difference to the example but I can't understand how it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all classes is the `props` which came from `withStyles` hoc. `styles` is the function where you define your style css. So, make sure you import everything properly. In `styles` variable, it can be pure object as well which means it doesn't have to be a function.

```
// import statements

const styles = theme => ({
    "myCustomClass": {
        fontFamily: "Arial"
    }
})

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ...
    }

    render () {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return <div className={classes.myCustomClass}>My custom class</div>
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Great stuff, but how do I instantiate a component that I style in this way in another .js file? Can't seem to find an example of that anywhere.

Comment: Ahh.. What you mean? You wanna use the same style across different components ? If that's the question, maybe you wanna create a function in separate file which returns style object and import it in the component you want ? If that's not the question, could you please provide more details.

Comment: Turns out I totally misunderstood the syntax of "export default withStyles(styles)(App);" haha. I thought that to use the component, there was some function to call with a style parameter. I didn't realize that you can use the component the same way regardless of high-order-component or hook styling approach. I haven't used JS in a couple of years and I didn't recognize some of the syntax. Sorry for the confusion - this example works great!

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle glad it helps :)